# Else clause application in python exceptions handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

For *handling exceptions* in python we use this pattern:

```
try:
   # do something
except NameError:
   # Do something for NameError exceptions
except:
   # Do something for other exceptions
   raise
else: 
   # Do something when didn't exist any exception
finally: 
   # Do something whether an exception has occurred or not
#rest of codes
```

My question is:

***What is the difference between `# do something for else` and `# rest of codes` ?*** Which one is preferable to another and more principled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help I took from [seysen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10182832/seysen) in the implementation of a simple example of my code, and good notice that was in comments of [sanyash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9609843/sanyash) ,this answer came to my mind and I think:

> *This is deeply dependent on the handling of the exceptions.*
>
> In other words, the behavior of `else` and the behavior of `#rest of codes` depends entirely on how the exceptions was handled.

*Consider these conditions:*

```
1. `try` run successfully:
 1.1 `else` will be executed. 
 1.2  `#rest of codes` will be executed.
2. Exception exist in `try` : 
    2.1 If we have `except: ... raise` or do not have a any handler:
        2.1.1  Built-in exception or `except: ... raise` will be executed. 
        2.1.2  Because we have exception: `else` will not be executed.
        2.1.3  Because the program stops: `#rest of codes` will not be executed.
    2.2 If there is an exception handler and program goes exactly inside of this handler: 
        2.2.1  Because we have exception: `else` will not be executed.  
        2.2.2 `#rest of codes` will be executed.
```

**So, the main difference arises when we adopt different approaches to handle exceptions.**

Answer (score 2):

The `else` block will execute before the `finally` block, the "rest of code" block will execute after the `finally` block.

If you don't have a `finally` block then there isn't really any difference, and I suspect dropping the `else` block completely would result in cleaner and more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

`# do something for else` will do something only if there's no exception.

While `# rest of codes` will do something always. Otherwise its an order of operations.

Comment: _While # rest of codes will do something always._ - if code goes to `except: ... raise` it will not be executed because of raised exception.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to demonstrate with example, so I edited your code slightly, to only focus on relevant parts.

```py
lst = [123, 512, 251]
for i in range(6):
    try:
       print(lst[i])
    except IndexError:
       print(f"Index {i} not there")
    else: 
       print("HELLO")
    finally:
       pass
    print("WORLD")
```

This was output:

```py
123
HELLO
WORLD
512
HELLO
WORLD
251
HELLO
WORLD
Index 3 not there
WORLD
Index 4 not there
WORLD
Index 5 not there
WORLD
```

So, as you can see, when the code in `try` block is run successfully, the code in `else` block is also run. But the code is `#rest of the codes` is run independently.